# How many "I"s am I talking about? : Asks Grandpa

Tags: riddle, knowledge

Grandpa is sitting there with his poker face

"Tell me son" He says calmly.

> "If 4**J**s equal 12**I**s
>
> 4**K**s equal 14**I**s
>
> How many **I**s does 1**Q** equals? And no, it is not 6.5 or 6.
>
> And while you are at it, tell me, how many **I**s do 2**A**s equal? Not a math question son"

Got me thinking.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think that 1**Q** equals

> 4 **I**s

Reasoning

> This is counting the number of eyes on the playing cards **J**ack, **K**ing and **Q**ueen. The Jacks have 12 eyes in total, the Kings have 14 and the Queens have 16 (4 on each card).

By this reasoning 2**A**s equals

> 0 **I**s

Comment: Note the other relevant clue of rot13(cbxre snpr).